# Getting value from NsDIctionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, nsdictionary

[image]Hey guys I am trying to get a Value from my firebase firestore and I seem to keep getting these multiple payload values instead of the value I am looking for. Here is what I currently have :

```
                let motoGPRiders = db.collection("riders").whereField("game_type", isEqualTo: "MOTOGP").addSnapshotListener { (QuerySnapshot, Error) in
                let allDocuments = QuerySnapshot!.documents

                for riderDocument in allDocuments {

                    let data = riderDocument.data()

                    // Get the rider list
                    guard let riderList  = data["game_type_riders"] as? NSMutableArray else { return }


                    var x = riderList[0] as! NSMutableDictionary

                    var riderName =  x["name"]
                    var y = ""


                }
```

and here is what is in x :

payload_data_0  NSString    "Joe"   0xd9200b3dfae6b8f0

payload_data_1  Builtin.RawPointer  0x0 0x0000000000000000
payload_data_2  Builtin.RawPointer  0x600001471840  0x0000600001471840

Included is a screenshot of my db data as well any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **NSMutableArray** to **[Any]** and **NSMutableDictionary** to **[String: Any]**.

Here is the full code.

```
let motoGPRiders = db.collection("riders").whereField("game_type", isEqualTo: "MOTOGP").addSnapshotListener { (QuerySnapshot, Error) in
                let allDocuments = QuerySnapshot!.documents

                for riderDocument in allDocuments {

                    let data = riderDocument.data()

                    // Get the rider list
                    guard let riderList  = data["game_type_riders"] as? [Any] else { return }


                    guard let x = riderList[0] as? [String: Any] else { return }

                    guard var riderName =  x["name"] as? String else { return }
                    var y = ""

                }
```